# what are the ways to align conditions in cases

Tags: math-mode, formatting, cases

For example, the following is not very nice:

```
[f(x)]_N=\begin{cases}
f(x)  \text{       if } f(x) \le N, \\
\newline N  \text{     if } f(x) \gt N.
\end{cases}
```

How can I make it nicer?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert ampersands `&` as alignment symbols:

```
$[f(x)]_N=\begin{cases}
    f(x) &\text{ if } f(x) \le N, \\
    \newline N &\text{ if } f(x) > N.
 \end{cases}$
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I would delete the `\newline` in the answer; if more vertical space is needed, there's `\\[3ex]` (or any other dimension).

Comment: @egreg: good tip! I just modified the code in the question for the desired horizontal alignment. `\newline` shouldn't be there.